# Unique Logger Name per class

Tags: ngx-logger

I my Angular application, I use NGXLogger,  but the loggername is always the same

> **[app-app-module.js:2740]**

regardless of where the logging takes place.

If would expect the logger name to reflect the module name that has the log.debug('x')

```
import { NGXLogger } from 'ngx-logger';

constructor (private logger: NGXLogger) 
  {
    _log = logger; 
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us which line is `[app-app-module.js:2740]`?

Comment: export class SidebarComponent extends SagerSystems.ComponentBase implements OnInit ...       Then I log the data.   **_log.debug(this.menuItems);**    I would assume the log would be [SidebarComponen .ts:2740]

Answer (score 1):

In order to see a "clear" component name you need to set `enableSourceMaps` to true in logger config

Be careful, for this to work you need to generate source maps when building

More info in the doc : https://github.com/dbfannin/ngx-logger/blob/master/docs/features.md